# DotNetOpenAuth - Using OpenIdButton for Google Apps

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, google-apps

I am an ASP.NET newbie and I am trying to design an OpenID/SSO system for an internal web application.  The web application is pretty simple and the authentication is currently being managed by a database with usernames and passwords.  I want to replace the existing accounts stored in the database with Google Apps accounts.

I have downloaded the latest DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.3.10103 package and got the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms sample up and running on IIS.  I have built my own login page using just a OpenIdButton object that points to a development Google domain.

The button seems to work fine in FireFox, at least it is forwarding me to the Google Apps login, but nothing happens when I load the same page in IE.  When I click the Google button, nothing happens, zip. The same is true for the Yahoo button in the login.aspx page given in the sample.

Here is the .aspx code I am using...

```
<rp:OpenIdButton runat="server" ImageUrl="http://www.google.com/accounts/google_transparent.gif" Text="Login with Google!" ID="googleLoginButton" Identifier="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=dev.connexcloud.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Google Apps Marketplace tutorial for .NET answers your question:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.html